# How frequently does mutex::lock() check for the unlocked state if it's already locked by another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex, stdthread

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard/lock_guard), constructing an `std::lock_guard` with a `std::mutex` parameter calls the `lock()` method of that `mutex`.

According to [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/lock/), regarding `mutex`’s `lock()` method:

> If the mutex is locked by another thread, execution of the calling
>   thread is blocked until unlocked by the other thread...

I'm not sure if the titular question is worded properly, so I put it in the context of the below code.

I wanted to test this and see if a calling thread actually waits for the unlocking instead of terminating execution of its callable (e.g. function, functor, lambda) and/or throwing an exception. The following code has two threads `t1` and `t2`, each constructed with a pointer to the same function `foo`. Each call to `foo` will `sleep_for` a certain amount of time, determined by `foo`'s `unsigned` parameter `num`, before executing the lock-protected code. The lock-protected code itself contains another `sleep_for` period, to make any blocked execution period more obvious:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex m;

void foo(unsigned num) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(num * 10));
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3000));
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(foo, 10);
    std::thread t2(foo, 5);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Console Output:

```
5
10
```

It takes about/at least 3.05 seconds for the `5` to output. It takes about/at least an additional 3 seconds for the `10` to output. This means `t2` gets to execute the protected code first, since it has the lesser wait time prior to the locking of the `mutex`.

I’m assuming once the call to `foo` from thread `t1` gets to the `lock_guard` line and finds the `mutex` had already been locked by `t2`, `t1` doesn’t terminate execution or throw an exception. `t1` just waits for it to be unlocked.

How frequently does `std::mutex::lock()` or `std::lock_guard` make this check for the unlocking? How costly is the check? Is the check implemented like the following?

```
while (some_mutex.try_lock() == false) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1))
}
// execute lock-protected code
```

Answer (score 4):

> How frequently does std::mutex::lock() or std::lock_guard make this check for the unlocking?

It doesn't. It blocks inside the operating system until the resource is released. Any operating system that implemented this by spinning would be cause for complaint.

Comment: Without spinning, how is it possible `std::mutex::lock()` can be cued to lock nearly right after another thread has released its lock?

Comment: By *scheduling.* Same as if the thread became runnable for any other reason, e.g. sleep expiry, I/O completion, or even just getting round to be scheduled again after being de-scheduled.

Comment: By, “It doesn’t…Any operating system that implemented this by spinning would be cause for complaint”, do you mean: “It can, but would be bad design”? Lightness Races in Orbit’s answer states it’s determined by the OS, and not implemented or specified by the standard.

Comment: 'Cause for complaint'?  It would a be a complete disaster, defeating the basic purpose of preemptive multitasking OS designs - to match up requests with those resources able to handle them. The OP question displays an all-too-common misconception of modern OS kernel functionality.

Comment: CodeBricks I meant something considerably stronger than that. See @MartinJames' comment, with which I entirely agree. Your question is basically a straw man, oddly enough.

Comment: There’s a difference between a possible implementation’s being “prohibited by the standard” and “not prohibited by the standard but never implemented in practice”. I just want to know which one it is. I am rephrasing the question in my previous comment to: “Does the standard prohibit spinning implementations?”

Comment: Since C++ does not provide the implementation, it cannot prohibit any implementation scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Mutexes are typically provided by the OS, meaning your OS's threading model is responsible for all of this. These details are not specified or even implemented by C++ at all.

As such, to a degree, it will depend on a number of factors such as CPU load across all processes, relative process priority, relative thread priority...

There's just far too much going on to give a clear-cut answer for you, even if such a thing would be useful.

Comment: @EJP: Nonsense. At some layer of abstraction, there is spinning, even if it's at the _transistor_ level. There is no such thing as a magical piece of software that just suddenly bursts into life when some condition is fulfilled without checking that condition. But since this is likely _deep_ within the OS, it's not worth rationalising about.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit err.. except for the concept of hardware interrupts, which are at the core of all modern preemptive, multitasking OS.  There is no need for spinning anywhere.  An idle system, with no current inputs, is doing nothing.  The cores are stuck on a 'halt' instruction, waiting for an interrupt.  No instructions are being fetched, no instructions are being executed, the buses are idle, nothing is happening.  No spinning, no logic gates are changing state, no transistors are turning on and off, nothing.  No spinning.  It's not deep within the OS, it's deep in the hardware.

Comment: @MartinJames: I'll grant you that - what I meant to say was "deep within the computer". I don't know enough about interrupts to give accurate details about them, but at some level _something_ has to spin, right? Even if, at that layer, it's not _quite_ the same sort of spinning as we'd describe in software?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - no, not really,  All cores can be completely halted, with nothing happening at all, until a hardware interrupt input pin/line is asserted. When that occurs, (just logic gates, no spinning:), the interrupt controller hardware follows an interrupt-acknowledge bus protocol to identify what peripheral device asserted the interrupt, fetches the matching interrupt-vector from a table, loads a core program counter with it and triggers the release of that core from the halted state. Usually, the vector points to a device driver entry point.

Comment: @MartinJames: Something has to cause the interrupt. Realistically, though, there are plenty of mutex-release scenarios that do not involve peripheral activity...